# Standard deviation and if in excel

Tags: excel, standard-deviation

I'm a problem with one of my formula in excel. The formula is supposed to return the standard deviation of an range of cells if the value is not judged to be an outlier in another column.

My formula is `STDAFV.S(HVIS(R2:R15<>"Outlier";P2:P15;""))`
The problem is that it returns a wrong value. In the example below, the formula returns a wrong value of `0.010729`, which should be `0.001652`.

I'm well aware, that this is a array formula, thus I do press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. So this is not the issue!

Does anyone have a clue for what is wrong?

> Col P | Col R
>
> 0.0215|
> 0.0207|
> 0.0233|
> 0.0213|
> 0.0187|
> 0.0917| Outlier

Comment: Try without the `...;"")` in the inner IF function

Comment: It do not work. It still return the wrong value.

Comment: tried with your data ... `{=STDEV.S(IF(C2:C7<>"Outlier";B2:B7))}` works well ... do you see curly brackets around your formula ... are all values in your set numeric ... I can paste my sheet ... BTW ... `STDDEV` of all values incl. Outlier here computes to `0,02886033` which indicates that your result of `0,010729` may point to a different problem ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same result as you when I am computing STDDEV across the 6 values of your OP **including 7 empty cells** as in your formula (`P2:P15`)

By doing so I add 7 times a **value = 0** to the set which will affect the mean value and the divisor (N-1) in the STDDEV formula.

If I limit the range from row 2 to 7 ... the ones actually containing data, I get the result you're expecting.

**Edit:**

To circumvent the problem of empty cells without redefinig the range everytime you can make use of `=COUNT()` and `=OFFSET()` functions ...

Your values are placed in a growing list, but without empty cells between. So the number of cells (=rows) is the result of a `=COUNT(B2:B1000)`

Your effective data range now is "from B2 and [count result] cells down" ... i.e. `=OFFSET(B2;0;0;COUNT(B2:B1000);1)`

Likewise, your effective comment range now is "from C2 and [count result in B] cells down" ... i.e. `=OFFSET(C2;0;0;COUNT(B2:B1000);1)`

Combining all this ... with data in B2:B15 and remark in C2:C15, the array formula becomes

{   `=STDEV.S(IF(OFFSET(C2;0;0;COUNT(B2:B15);1)<>"Outlier";OFFSET(B2;0;0;COUNT(B2:B15);1)))`  }

[image]

ta-taaaa!

Comment: Ah, I see now. When I shrink the range until the only 2 to 7 rows, I get the expected number.
However, in time more values will be add to these columns, and I would think, it is annoying to adjust the STDDEV range very time. Is there a work around that?

Comment: Yes indeed ... see my Edit

Comment: I see, how this would makes sense. However, it seems, that in the remark column, COUNT returns a zero even though it contains a outlier remark in the 7th row.Thus makes giving me an reference error. COUNT does not count texts? And if it did, would it return 1 instead of 7.

Comment: Ahhh... I know realize my mistake. I had change the COUNT for the remark to count in the remark column instead of value colmun Thank very much!

Comment: in my example the `=COUNT()` in both cases counts the data, not the comments ... see highlights in red in the pic.